# AirScan / eSCL protocol input source change from Platen to ADF for Xerox WorkCentre 3345

Tags: scanning, airprint

I have a Xerox WorkCentre 3345 multifunctional printer/scanner. I claims that it supports eSCL protocol for driverless scanning. **I can scan with it to the input source called 'Platen'.** The problem is no matter how I try **it does not scan from the 'ADF' input source**.

What XML do I need to send to be able to scan from ADF?

The ScannerCapabilities file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scan:ScannerCapabilities xmlns:pwg="http://www.pwg.org/schemas/2010/12/sm" xmlns:scan="http://schemas.hp.com/imaging/escl/2011/05/03">
<pwg:Version>2.5</pwg:Version>
<pwg:MakeAndModel>WorkCentre 3345</pwg:MakeAndModel>
<pwg:SerialNumber>3387495346</pwg:SerialNumber>
<scan:Platen>
    <scan:PlatenInputCaps>
        <scan:MinWidth>1</scan:MinWidth>
        <scan:MaxWidth>2560</scan:MaxWidth>
        <scan:MinHeight>1</scan:MinHeight>
        <scan:MaxHeight>3507</scan:MaxHeight>
        <scan:SettingProfiles>
            <scan:SettingProfile>
                <scan:ColorModes>
                    <scan:ColorMode>BlackAndWhite1</scan:ColorMode>
                    <scan:ColorMode>Grayscale8</scan:ColorMode>
                    <scan:ColorMode>RGB24</scan:ColorMode>
</scan:ColorModes>
                <scan:DocumentFormats>
                    <pwg:DocumentFormat>application/pdf</pwg:DocumentFormat>
                    <scan:DocumentFormatExt>application/pdf</scan:DocumentFormatExt>
                    <pwg:DocumentFormat>image/jpeg</pwg:DocumentFormat>
                    <scan:DocumentFormatExt>image/jpeg</scan:DocumentFormatExt>
</scan:DocumentFormats>
                <scan:SupportedResolutions>
                    <scan:DiscreteResolutions>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>100</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>100</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>200</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>200</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>300</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>300</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>600</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>600</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolutions>
</scan:SupportedResolutions>
</scan:SettingProfile>
</scan:SettingProfiles>
        <scan:SupportedIntents>
            <scan:Intent>Document</scan:Intent>
            <scan:Intent>TextAndGraphic</scan:Intent>
            <scan:Intent>Photo</scan:Intent>
</scan:SupportedIntents>
        <scan:MaxOpticalXResolution>600</scan:MaxOpticalXResolution>
        <scan:MaxOpticalYResolution>600</scan:MaxOpticalYResolution>
</scan:PlatenInputCaps>
</scan:Platen>
<scan:Adf>
    <scan:AdfSimplexInputCaps>
        <scan:MinWidth>1</scan:MinWidth>
        <scan:MaxWidth>5120</scan:MaxWidth>
        <scan:MinHeight>1</scan:MinHeight>
        <scan:MaxHeight>4200</scan:MaxHeight>
        <scan:SettingProfiles>
            <scan:SettingProfile>
                <scan:ColorModes>
                    <scan:ColorMode>BlackAndWhite1</scan:ColorMode>
                    <scan:ColorMode>Grayscale8</scan:ColorMode>
                    <scan:ColorMode>RGB24</scan:ColorMode>
</scan:ColorModes>
                <scan:DocumentFormats>
                    <pwg:DocumentFormat>application/pdf</pwg:DocumentFormat>
                    <scan:DocumentFormatExt>application/pdf</scan:DocumentFormatExt>
                    <pwg:DocumentFormat>image/jpeg</pwg:DocumentFormat>
                    <scan:DocumentFormatExt>image/jpeg</scan:DocumentFormatExt>
</scan:DocumentFormats>
                <scan:SupportedResolutions>
                    <scan:DiscreteResolutions>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>100</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>100</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>200</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>200</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>300</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>300</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
                        <scan:DiscreteResolution>
                            <scan:XResolution>600</scan:XResolution>
                            <scan:YResolution>600</scan:YResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolution>
</scan:DiscreteResolutions>
</scan:SupportedResolutions>
</scan:SettingProfile>
</scan:SettingProfiles>
        <scan:SupportedIntents>
            <scan:Intent>Document</scan:Intent>
            <scan:Intent>TextAndGraphic</scan:Intent>
            <scan:Intent>Photo</scan:Intent>
</scan:SupportedIntents>
        <scan:MaxOpticalXResolution>600</scan:MaxOpticalXResolution>
        <scan:MaxOpticalYResolution>600</scan:MaxOpticalYResolution>
</scan:AdfSimplexInputCaps>
    <scan:FeederCapacity>100</scan:FeederCapacity>
    <scan:AdfOptions>
        <scan:AdfOption>DetectPaperLoaded</scan:AdfOption>
</scan:AdfOptions>
</scan:Adf>
</scan:ScannerCapabilities>
```

I can scan with the following XML to Platen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scan:ScanSettings xmlns:pwg="http://www.pwg.org/schemas/2010/12/sm"
                   xmlns:scan="http://schemas.hp.com/imaging/escl/2011/05/03">
  <pwg:Version>2.5</pwg:Version>
  <pwg:ScanRegions>
    <pwg:ScanRegion>
      <pwg:Height>3507</pwg:Height>
      <pwg:Width>2560</pwg:Width>
      <pwg:XOffset>0</pwg:XOffset>
      <pwg:YOffset>0</pwg:YOffset>
    </pwg:ScanRegion>
  </pwg:ScanRegions>
  <pwg:InputSource>Platen</pwg:InputSource> <!-- Changing this line to Adf or AdfSimplex does not help!-->
  <scan:ColorMode>Grayscale8</scan:ColorMode>
  <scan:XResolution>600</scan:XResolution>
  <scan:YResolution>600</scan:YResolution>
  <pwg:DocumentFormat>application/pdf</pwg:DocumentFormat>
  <scan:Intent>Document</scan:Intent>
</scan:ScanSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line:

```
<pwg:InputSource>Feeder</pwg:InputSource>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. How did you know that? I could not find any documentation.

Comment: I've wrote a full-function SANE backend for AirScan: https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan